# Robocopy - Copying folders and files doesn't recreate directory structure

Tags: windows, robocopy

Well, it kind of does but skips one level I think. So, here's folder structure I have (Windows 2008 R2 SP2 standard):

```
ClientA
   |_ClientAfolder1
   |_ClientAfolder2

ClientB
   |_ClientBfolder1
   |_ClientBfolder2
```

And so forth...
Here's the script I'm using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "folderlist.txt" ') do robocopy "%%a" "Z:\temp\test" /E /xo /fft /COPYALL /r:0 /w:0
```

My folderlist.txt looks like this:

```
f:\ClientA\ClientAfolder1
f:\ClientA\ClientAfolder2
f:\ClientB\ClientBfolder1
f:\ClientB\ClientBfolder2
```

And after executing the script, my folder structure becomes like this:

```
   ClientAfolder1
   ClientAfolder2
   ClientBfolder1
   ClientBfolder2
```

So, it skips creating parent folders which are ClientA and ClientB. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You didn't *ask* it to create the parent folders.  You asked it to copy (for example) `ClientA` overtop of `z:\temp\test` so that's what you got.  If you want it to copy `ClientA` to `z:\temp\test\ClientA`, tell it that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("folderlist.txt") do (
    robocopy "%%a" "Z:\temp\test%%~pnxa" /E /xo /fft /COPYALL /r:0 /w:0
)
```